# Selecting stored in variable

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm trying to create a shopping cart for a college assignment, I'm trying to load a table from the contents of a variable but regardless of what I do it won't recognise its contents.

Here the code snippet

`$sql = sprintf("SELECT name, description, price FROM %s WHERE id = %d;",$table, $product_id); 
 $result = mysql_query($sql);`

The table variables contents is being missed out so its looking a nameless table, I've searched Google and found a couple of examples but are working for me.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks Scott.

Comment: How are you setting `$table`?

Comment: Lol yeah definitely setting $table I’ve echoed its contents, it has the table name stored

Comment: Your example works as expected when $table and $product_id are defined. Examine your code for typos, you might be setting a variable with a different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should recognize your variable:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT name, description, price FROM " .$table. " WHERE id = %d", product_id); 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks again Charley14 but still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query take 2 parameters, one is your query and other is connection to your database so you need to do the following
$result = mysql_query($sql,your connection variable); `

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the sql query's not the problem, if I change where I trying to use $table and instead just write the name of the table it works fine. The issue is it's not recognising the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking off the semicolon after WHERE id = %d

Comment: Thanks for reply, still getting the same problem